# select 1 Although have few users.. mysql

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, rows

why $subadmin = 1 row only?

i have few users with "MaTeam = 8"
but its select 1 user only!

my code:

```
$query8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MaTeam='8';");
$subadmin = array();
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($query8)) {
$subadmin=$rowa["username"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `while` loop is overwriting the `$subadmin` value on every iteration.  To append to your array you can use `[]` after the array variable name:

```
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($query8)) {
    $subadmin[] = $rowa["username"];
}
```

(Side note: Consider switching to the mysqli library since the older mysql library is deprecated.)

Comment: $subadmin is now an array filled with usernames.  I don't know what you mean by "no user is selected".  Maybe we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($query8)) {
  $subadmin = $rowa["username"];
```

with:

```
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
  $subadmin[] = $rowa["username"];
```

Comment: Did you try using mysql_fetch_assoc and $subadmin[]=$rowa["username"];?